# How to use turn detection in opensmile

Tags: audio

I'm trying to use voice activity detector in OpenSMILE following [this tutorial](http://records.mlab.no/2015/01/05/opensmile-the-munich-open-source-large-scale-multimedia-feature-extractor-a-tutorial-for-version-2-1/), but when I run the command:

```
SMILExtract -I ../../example-audio/media-interpretation.wav -C vad_segmenter.conf -waveoutput voice_segments/segment
```

I get the following output:

```
(MSG) [2] in configManager : reading config file 'turnDetector.conf'
(MSG) [2] in configManager : config file 'turnDetector.conf' not found, trying to open 'vad_segmenter.conf/turnDetector.conf'.
(ERROR) [1] in configManager : cFileConfigReader::openInput : cannot open input file 'vad_segmenter.conf/turnDetector.conf'! terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cConfigException'
```

I've noticed that the file doesn't exist in the [github repo](https://github.com/naxingyu/opensmile/tree/master/scripts/vad), I tried to google it but with no results, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I found out I had an older version of OpenSMILE, I solved the problem by downloading the last one.